# Notation Meaning

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, notation

For the probability density function property function:

$\int _X^{\:}\:f_X\left(x\right)dx=1$

What does the notation of an integral with a $X$ only at the bottom mean (such as in that property)?
I am looking for what it means in general, not specifically for that property.

Comment: Integrate over the set X.

Comment: I've not seen that notation before, but my best guess: $X$ in this context means "the set of values that the random variable $X$ can be." (That's assuming $X$ is a random variable here; if it's not, the answers of others seem right.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is notation to indicate that the integral is over the set $X$.
For instance,

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$$

could be written as

$$\int_{[0,1]} f(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: Additionally, here the set $X$ is likely to be the support for the random variable.